# Desktop.ini InfoTip not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, filesystems, desktop.ini

I'm trying to utilize some of the capabilities of *desktop.ini* in Windows to help organize the network file system at work.

Most network folders need an **Archive** folder at various levels in the filesystem, so I've been able to use *desktop.ini* to change the icon to help visually distinguish the folder. However, I've got some automatically generated information about the Archive folder and/or its parent folder that I'd like to apply to the ToolTip, but the **InfoTip** property doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here's what I have in my *desktop.ini* file:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
ConfirmFileOp=0
NoSharing=1
IconFile=%windir%\system32\moricons.dll
IconIndex=-66
InfoTip=An archive of {Part} folder documents
```

I've also ensured the following:

- File is Unicode format
- File has **both** *Hidden* and *System* attributes

Am I missing something or is this functionality no longer available?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what is missing if what is explained in following answer

[How to get Windows to read copied desktop.ini file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1117824/how-to-get-windows-to-read-copied-desktop-ini-file)