# How to get Windows to read copied desktop.ini file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, icons, desktop.ini

I have a folder with a custom icon and its setting is stored in `desktop.ini` I believe. I wanted to apply that same icon to a bunch of folders. So I thought simply copying `desktop.ini` to any other folder would do the job, but Windows Explorer doesn't update the folder icon by reading from the newly copied `desktop.ini` file.

How to get Windows to read copied desktop.ini file?

Comment: Related: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150325-00/?p=44393/ and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030930-00/?p=42353/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply the read-only attribute for each folder. From a Command Prompt window, type:

> attrib +r path\folder

This will make Explorer process the `desktop.ini` file for that folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed to set the read-only attribute to several dozens of folders, so I came up with a couple of command lines to help doing this faster.

Here I wanted to do this to every folders in D:, just replace it with the specific path to the group of folders you'd want to affect :

```
attrib +r D:* /s /d
```

First this would give the readonly attribute to every single thing

```
attrib -r D:* /s
```

Then this would remove back readonly from every single *file* (excluding folders).

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense. Microsoft tells us to use `attrib +s folderPath` ([reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini)), which works great for me (*technically, using `+s` or `+r` both work, because the `+s` is transposed to `+r` on file folders*).

But then again, they say to use the `PathMakeSystemFolder` `PInvoke` to do the same thing, but I tried it until the cow came to the barn to empty their swollen utters, but it "failed", though the `Boolean` result indicates success (*be sure the filepath string for `PathMakeSystemFolderW` is marshaled to `LPWSTR`*).

It even set the folder's `Read-Only` flag, which a folder needs to even consider the `dekstop.ini` file, which must in turn have attributes `Hidden` and `System` set. I later found out that attrib `+s` will set these two attributes on `desktop.ini`, if found in the target folder, but `PathMakeSystemFolder` does not.

As a 40+ year Assembler and C++ Software Designer and Engineer, I *should* have already known that this `PInvoke` would only do the one task! Thus, just as the MS article pointed out (*if we would only read it the way they want us to, not the way we want to*), we also have to ensure the `desktop.ini` file attributes are also set to `System` and `Hidden`. Just when I think "I are smart!"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1191219)